# Bootstrap modal is visible even it shouldn't be

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, pyramid, mako

I have a bootstrap modal which contains other modals too, problem is that when visiting a page first time, this main modal is shown even thou i haven't clicked any buttons to trigger it. modal is almost functional in this stage, buttons that trigger other modals work, but closing buttons for this main modal doesn't work. after i click show 'main modal' button, rest of the page goes dark(this means that now modal is triggered(active) and everything works like it should be, even closing buttons.

I tried to use javascript that hides this main modal automatically but it didn't work, nothing different happened, but same script that automatically shows this main modal, triggers main modal correctly, but i don't wanna trigger that modal every-time when someone visits the page.

Here is my code for the main modal in a mako template:

```
<%inherit file="../base.mak"/>


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#linkEditor">
  Launch demo modal
</button>




<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="linkEditor" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Link editor</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">


        <form class="form-horizontal.form-actions " action="${request.route_url('link')}" method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span3">
                    <h4>Search links</h4>
                    <input name="keyword" type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Search links">

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>

                </div>
            </div>   
        </form>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-small" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editLink">
        Edit a link
        </button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-small" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createLink">
        Create a link
        </button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-small" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteLink">
        Delete a link
        </button>

        <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>URL</th>
                <th>Shortcode</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            % for link in links:
            <tr onclick="selectLink(${link.id})">
                <td>${link.name}</td>
                <td>${link.url}</td>
                <td>${link.shortcode}</td>       
            </tr>
            % endfor

            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Select link</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is my python server side code:

```
#path from the __init__.py
config.add_route('link','/link')

@view_config(route_name='link', renderer='protos:templates/link/link.mak')
def link(request):
    session = DBSession()
    keyword = None

    if (u'keyword' in request.POST.keys()):
        keyword = request.POST.get(u'keyword')

    if not keyword == None:
        #add order by something later?
        #better logic for the searching?
        links = session.query(mail_link).filter(or_(
                        mail_link.name.like ('%' + keyword + '%'),
                        mail_link.url.like ('%' + keyword + '%'),
                        mail_link.shortcode.like ('%' + keyword + '%')
                        )).all()

    else:
        links = session.query(mail_link).all()

    return {'links': links}
```

Thanks for the time and help.

Comment: 'hide', of course. now i feel silly. Thx :)

Comment: We've all been there :)